# Indicating the end of a raw data chunk in an RLE algorithm that can contain all byte values

Tags: c#, compression, byte, run-length-encoding

I'm writing an RLE algorithm in C# that can work on any file as input. The approach to encoding I'm taking is as follows:

An RLE packet contains 1 byte for the length and 1 byte for the value. For example, if the byte `0xFF` appeared 3 times in a row, `0x03 0xFF` would be written to the file.

If representing the data as raw data would be more efficient, I use `0x00` as a terminator. This works because the length of a packet can never be zero. If I wanted to add the bytes `0x53 0x2C 0x01` to my compressed file it would look like this:

`0x03 0xFF 0x00 0x53 0x2C 0x01`

However a problem arises when trying to switch back to RLE packets. I can't use a byte as a terminator like I did for switching onto raw data because any byte value from `0x00 to 0xFF` can be in the input data, and when decoding the bytes the decoder would misinterpret the byte as a terminator and ruin everything.

What can I do to indicate that I have to switch back to RLE packets when it can't be written as data in the file?

Here is my code if it helps:

```
private static void RunLengthEncode(ref byte[] bytes)
{
    // Create a list to store the bytes
    List<byte> output = new List<byte>();
    
    byte runLengthByte;
    int runLengthCounter = 0;

    // Set the RLE byte to the first byte in the array and increment the RLE counter
    runLengthByte = bytes[0];

    // For each byte in the input array...
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (runLengthByte == bytes[i] || runLengthCounter == 255)
        {
            runLengthCounter++;
        }
        else 
        {
            // RLE packets under 3 should be written as raw data to avoid increasing the file size
            if (runLengthCounter < 3)
            {
                // Add a 0x00 to indicate raw data
                output.Add(0x00);

                // Add the bytes that were skipped while counting the run length
                for (int j = i - runLengthCounter; j < i; j++)
                {
                    output.Add(bytes[j]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Add 2 bytes, one for the number of bytes and one for the value
                output.Add((byte)runLengthCounter);
                output.Add(runLengthByte);
            }

            runLengthCounter = 1;
            runLengthByte = bytes[i];
        }
            
        // Add the last bytes to the list when finishing
        if (i == bytes.Length - 1)
        {
            // Add 2 bytes, one for the number of bytes and one for the value
            output.Add((byte)runLengthCounter);
            output.Add(runLengthByte);
        }
    }

    // Set the bytes to the RLE encoded data
    bytes = output.ToArray();
}
```

Also if you want to comment and say that RLE isn't very efficient for binary data, I know it isn't. This is a project I'm doing to implement many kinds of compression to learn about them, not for an actual product.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: A simple solution could be adding an extra byte after the terminator to indicate the length of the raw bytes.

Comment: @shingo so when finding a section that would be raw data, read forward in the array until a grouping of 3 or more bytes that can be represented as a RLE packet is found (or until the counter is more than 255), then just add how many steps it took to get there as a single byte. Makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to unambiguously encode run-lengths. One simple way is, when decoding: if you see two equal bytes in a row, then the next byte is a a count of repeats of that byte after those first two. I.e. 0..255 additional repeats, so encoding runs of 2..257. (There's no point in encoding runs of 0 or 1.)